# Tomcat 7 starts up my SSL-secured port without erroring, but is still not publicly accessible. How do I debug this?

Tags: ssl, https, tomcat

At my job I have been tasked with securing a website (http -> https)
I am new to this, so forgive me if my terminology is wrong.

I've spent the past week setting up Tomcat's keystores and configuring Tomcat's server.xml to get SSL working, and I've finally gotten it to the point where it tells me this:

```
Nov 04, 2019 9:48:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
Nov 04, 2019 9:48:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

8009 is my http port, which works fine.
8443 is my https port. From this output, it seems it should also be fine.
However, when I try to connect to my website using the https url, it times out. I can't find any logs, errors, or anything regarding this issue.

Things I have tried:

- Opening the 8443 (and 8000) port on iptables
- Testing the url/port on the server itself using `curl -il https://my.website.name:8443`, which gets me

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 ...
```

- Tunneling to Tomcat's 8000 debug port using PuTTY, then debugging the local version of that port in IntelliJ. All IntelliJ tells me is "Error ... Connection reset".
- Redoing all of the above with various random ports

My local machine is running Windows, but the website is on a Tomcat 7 server on a Scientific Linux machine that I can only access via SSH, which just complicates things further.

What else can I look at? Is there anything I should read? A log I should look at? I can most likely debug the issue myself if I just knew vaguely what the issue was, but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score -1):

My iptables entries weren't being permanently registered for some reason. My sysadmin got it sorted out.